# NetBeans: how to split window and place output panel to the right?

Tags: netbeans

By default NetBeans has projects on the left, open files on the top part of right panel and output/variables/... on the bottom part of the left panel. As a result file panel is wide and tall. Is it possible to reorganize panels, so that "projects" panel is on the left, "open files" panel is on the center and "output/variables/..." panel is on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done much the same way you split the string horizontally. Grub the page tab and move it until you see that the red rectangle indicating alignment appears vertically along the right side of screen. This works in NetBans 8.1 and above.